# Is there premodification in this noun phrase "too many victims"

Tags: phrases, nouns, determiners, noun-phrases, premodifiers

I have to analyze the noun phrase "too many victims" but I somehow can't figure out whether "too many" is a determiner or premodification. Given the fact *too* is an adverb and *many* is a determiner (quantifier) it doesn't make sense to me because that would go against the *dmhq* structure. Or is *many* in this context considered a pronoun?

Comment: No, many is not a pronoun here.

Comment: You could call ***too many*** an "attributive adjective" (comes *before* the noun it modifies). Semantically and syntactically equivalent to, say, ***excessive** [numbers of]*. In which context ***too*** is really just an intensifier for ***many*** - which I think would normally be classed as a "determiner". I don't know how that helps anyone to understand English constructions, though.

Comment: ...I never heard of  "the *dmhq* structure", but it sounds like it doesn't apply in the current context anyway. So what?

Comment: @ Alex I'd analyse "too many" as a **DP** (determinative phrase) with the determinative "many" as head, modified by the adverb "too". The DP then functions as **determiner** in the NP "too many victims".

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's for my thesis research in which I analyze modifications of noun phrases in various registers, the _dhmq_ structure is basically determiner-premodification-*head*-qualifier(postmodification). So I don't know, English isn't my native language, this is what I've learned in English Syntax classes at uni. 
Anyway, I did some digging in books and found the answer to my question: _too_ is an intensifying adverb which modifies the postmodfier _many_ which belongs to a closed-class quantifiers. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Alex You have that wrong. "Many" is a determinative. It is not a postmodifier, but head of the determinative phrase "too many" functioning as determiner in the NP "too many victims". The head of the DP is "many", which is modified by the adverb "too". Does that clarify things?

Comment: @BillJ my bad, I wanted to write postdeterminer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *They discovered* [*too many victims*].

"Too many victims" is a noun phrase with the noun "victims" functioning as head, and the DP (determinative phrase) "too many" functioning as determiner of the head.

The DP consists of the determinative "many" as head, and the adverb "too" as modifier of the head.